# What does the "a" at the end of a spectral type mean?

Tags: star, spectra, spectral-type

Looking at the chart for spectral type peculiarities ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Spectral_peculiarities)), I noticed that the letter **a** was missing from the chart. This seems to be an error, as the star Vega has spectral type A0Va, with the **a** definitely being a peculiarity. What does the **a** in spectral types mean, and is this actually a spectral peculiarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If present, an a (or b or ab) do not refer to spectral peculiarities but are part of the luminosity class definition explained further up on the page.

> Occasionally, letters a and b are applied to luminosity
> classes other than supergiants; for example, a giant star
> slightly less luminous than typical may be given a
> luminosity class of IIIb, while a luminosity class IIIa
> indicates a star slightly brighter than a typical giant.[27]